# How to create vectorized function in R, where each element of vector needs to be manipulated using subsetting some other dataframe?

Tags: r

How to create vectorized function in R, where each element of vector needs to be manipulated using subsetting some other dataframe?

This is what I tried -

```
my_func <- function(var1) {
    a_row <- subset(another_df,col1 == var1)[1,]
    return (a_row$col2)
}
```

this function doesn't work.

Comment: How about `lapply(yourvec, function(x) another_df$col2[another_df$col1==x])`

Comment: just use `my_fun <- Vectorize(function(var1) {...})`. See `?Vectorize` for more info

Comment: @akrun actually my need is - assign df1.vec1 (on some condition e.g. is.na() on df1.vec1 and df1.vec2) equal to the df2.vec1 where df2.vec2 is max. I hope, I am making sense.